# felix1982 None 0 Points 1 Post use asp.net mvc 5, occur one post but the corresponding action is performed several times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action

client code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreateBy)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>SOA项</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" id="btn_AddSOA" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;margin-right:20px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_soa" value="添加SOA模板" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class="form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                </div>
.....................
```

server code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit( SOAWorkItem soaworkitem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        LogHelper.WriteInfoLog("Edit2-"+soaworkitem.Name + "," + soaworkitem.SOAString);
        db.Entry(soaworkitem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(soaworkitem);
}
```

when click button to post page, by Fiddle,I can see, only have one http post, but In my log file,I see:

> 016-02-19 15:44:08,454 [134] INFO  loginfo [(null)]  -
>   Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6 2016-02-19 15:44:09,368 [43]
>   INFO  loginfo [(null)]  - Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6
>   2016-02-19 15:44:09,743 [134] INFO  loginfo [(null)]  -
>   Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,abcdefg 2016-02-19 15:44:09,790 [138] INFO 
>   loginfo [(null)]  - Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6 2016-02-19
>   15:44:09,909 [138] INFO  loginfo [(null)]  -
>   Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6 2016-02-19 15:44:09,997 [43]
>   INFO  loginfo [(null)]  - Edit2-abcdefg,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6 2016-02-19
>   15:44:10,133 [109] INFO  loginfo [(null)]  -
>   Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6 2016-02-19 15:44:10,287 [134]
>   INFO  loginfo [(null)]  - Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6
>   2016-02-19 15:44:10,378 [138] INFO  loginfo [(null)]  -
>   Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,abcdeefg 2016-02-19 15:44:10,502 [43]
>   INFO  loginfo [(null)]  - Edit2-SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6,SOA%C3%FB%B3%C6

Action is to be performed several times , In My localhost, application is right,but in  remote server with IIS, can occur the above problems, but i don't know why?